# Copying text to the user's clipboard

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Here's my code.

```
javascript:x=document.createElement("script");x.src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);copy(1)
```

Is this the correct way? Are there any flaws in it?

Running:

```
copy(1)
```

doesn't work by itself so that's not a possibility, and

```
javascript:x=document.createElement("script");x.src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);copy(1)
```

appears to be the best so far.

Comment: Is the expected result for data to be copied to the clipboard without user action?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Can you confirm that the code functions correctly? If so, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing (ideally as reproducible unit-test code).  If it's not working, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.

Comment: @guest271314 yes, after clicking the bookmarklet

Comment: @TobySpeight It works, how would I give proof?

Comment: Just [edit] to say how you've tested it, so that it's clear that it's not an off-topic question.  BTW, does the code need to be all on a single line?  It might be more readable if split across lines.

Comment: Bookmarklets are all on one line

Comment: An external library is not necessary to copy text to the clipboard. Where is `copy` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, except for polluting the namespace, you could consider using a [self executing anonymous function](https://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/).

```
javascript:(function(){x=document.createElement("script");x.src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);copy(1);})();
```

Comment: Have you tried the code at the answer? `Uncaught ReferenceError: copy is not defined`

Comment: I had, it seemed to work just fine for me. His form, and the self executing form did not throw an error for me. But I now see that my browser has a copy function [Command Line API] even before running the bookmarklet. That does not take away my feedback on polluting the namespace though.

Comment: @konijn it seems to work only in the console. have your tried in the bookmarklets?

Comment: There is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/106438/7602